# Liferay 6.2 remove sample data

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to remove sample data (Welcome screen and everything else) from my Liferay server.
I tried to:

- remove all directories from the webapps directory except ROOT directory
- create new (blank) portal-ext.properties in ROOT/WEB-inf/classes (there was no portal-ext.properties file)
- search via Google :)

Nothing of the above helped. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have configured a database, or are using the built-in demo hsql database. This holds all the regular data. If you've configured Liferay to access another database either remove the tables from that database or point to another one. There's also the document library that holds documents and images (the binary content). By default they all live in the data directory, on the same level as your tomcat directory (assuming you use a bundle)

A new blank portal-ext.properties will not help you, as it overrides all the standard values defined in Liferay. If there's no content, you're using all the default. And the file should rather be in ${liferay-home}, e.g. the directory that also has the tomcat directory in a bundle.

As you've removed all content and bundled webapplications anyway, you can also just install a new bundle in another directory and use it, pointing it to a new database.